# Creating unique identifier for cadastral parcels in ArcGIS 10.5?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, vbscript, arcgis-10.5

Creating unique identifier for cadastral parcels in ArcGIS 10.5 (ArcView)?

I'm adding selected parcels to a feature class and I would like to have a text prefix and then three or four digit number that increases as I add to the layer. The text prefix will be categorizing the type of parcel, the numbers will be for keeping a sequential count.

An old colleague gave me this script a few years ago, but no instruction.

```vbs
Static recz As Long
Dim lStart As Long
Dim lInterval As Long
Dim IMap As String
Dim IMapID As String
'=================
'adjust start value and interval bellow
lStart = 500
lInterval = 1
IMap = "G505"

'=================
If (recz = 0) Then
  recz = lStart
End If
recz = recz + lInterval
IMapID = IMap & "." & recz
```

Comment: That's a VB script as I'm sure you're aware, ArcGIS is moving away from VB so I think it would be better to use the python parser. Are you after a tool or a field calculator expression? I'd think it would be better if this was implemented as a tool with two stages: 1 - find the existing highest number, 2 - calculate the parcels without an identifier from the next number in the series. This *can* be done with a python field calculator expression but would be incredibly slow and get slower as the dataset grows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - we used it as a field calculator expression - adding 20 to 100 new parcels every few days. 
If I knew how to make a tool I would give it a try.
Does anyone know an equivalent expression that would work in 10.5?

I need to be able to set the prefix characters - and then add the sequential numbers.

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a straight translation into python field calculation:

```
gCurrentNum = 500    # Change this to the next available number
gInterval   = 1      # the step
gPrefix     = 'G505' # the prefix to the ID

def CalcID():
    # bring in the global variables
    global gCurrentNum
    global gInterval
    global gPrefix

    IMapID = '{}.{}'.format(gPrefix,gCurrentNum)
    gCurrentNum += gInterval # increment the current number by interval
    return IMapID            # return the unique identifier
```

But as I said it would be better as a tool trying to find the next starting number, this can be done in a field calculation but there are some dangers:

```
gCurrentNum = 0         # Change this to the next available number
gInterval   = 1         # the step
gPrefix     = 'G505'    # the prefix to the ID
gLayerName  = 'Parcels' # The name of the parcels layer
gFieldName  = 'ParcelID'# The field name containing the unique ID

# bypassing selection and definition queries read the
# feature class directly to make sure ALL rows are considered
Lay = arcpy.mapping.Layer(gLayerName)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Lyr.dataSource,gFieldName) as SCur:
    for row in SCur:
        if not row[0] == None:              # if there is something in the field
            SplitString = row[0].split('.')   # break up the string at the dot
            if len(SplitString > 1):          # if it's in the expected format prefix.number
                if SplitString[1].isdigit():    # if the second element is a number
                    ThisNum = int(SplitString[1]) # make the 2nd element a numeric type
                    if ThisNum > gCurrentNum:     # if more than the current number
                        gCurrentNum = ThisNum       # make the current number equal to this (highest) number
gCurrentNum += gInterval                # increment the current number or the first will be equal to the highest

def CalcID():
    # bring in the global variables
    global gCurrentNum
    global gInterval
    global gPrefix

    IMapID = '{}.{}'.format(gPrefix,gCurrentNum)
    gCurrentNum += gInterval # increment the current number by interval
    return IMapID            # return the unique identifier
```

This goes into field calculator with a python parser but it is **vital** that the layer name and field name as stated in the expression is correct, I've set them to arbitrary values but you **must** change the layer and field to match your data.